# How to keep a program running in background until user clicks its icon to make the window visible?

Tags: java, windows, background, jframe, window

I am creating a java program that behaves like the Windows' start menu. I want it to run at startup and keep running in the background. When the user clicks application icon i want the window to become visible and again dissapear when the user is finished. The reason i want it to keep running in background is to make the window appear quickly as there are lots of images that need to be preloaded.

Comment: So, you've basically described every program ever written (for a modern GUI OS), particularly those which run in the notification bar of the task bar

Comment: My program (i mean UI with which the user interacts) is ready and i have managed to run it at startup using a bat file and placing it in startup programs. But i cant make the window appear and dissapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your java application is based on Swing/AWT.

**Step1:** In Batch file/Shell script, please add & symbol at last and the java program will run it in background.

Example:
*Content of batch file / shell script*

```
java XYZ &
```

**Step2:** Please ensure that the your application has toplevel container which consists of

- Sub container which has  Icon (which is visible always)
- Sub container like Jpanel/JFrame are initially drawn/painted with
  'hide' option.

It ensures that your application is not visible to normal user, but icon container is visible

**Step3:** Based on user action on icon cotainer, you will hide/show the sub container of JPanel/JFrame.

**Step3:** Please ensure that icon of your application

Comment: Batch file's content-                                                         @echo off                                                                                       java myclass &                                                                             When i run the batch file the window still pops up and does not run in background.

Comment: & symbol is used for running it in background process. When you execute the batch file, it opens the command prompt by default.    Please try to execute the application as jar file. <b> Please refer the url: http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-.Jar-Java-File

Comment: Thanks, step 1 works fine.But i can't understand step 2. What i want is,suppose there is a desktop icon for my program. The program has its jframe set to non-visible (setVisible(false)) .when i click the icon then instead of opening another instance of application it sets the jframe to visible so that the application comes to foreground. Is there a way to do it?